# regarding android kernel

Tags: kernel

what exactly will happens when we start executing an activity which file will be invoked in the kernel level. I mean which .c class file or which header will be called can any one tell me in brief or the procedure. How the process takes place in the kernel level when an activity intiated.

Answer (score 2):

If the activity is triggered by some I/O event (e.g., pressing a button), then:

- You press the button
- The button generates an electric signal on an interrupt line
- This signals makes the system switch to kernel-mode and run the related Interrupt Service Routine in the Linux kernel
- The kernel runs the interrupt management in the driver related to the specific I/O controller
- Once the interrupt has been handled, depending on the communication between user-level and kernel-level, the kernel can signal the user-level (in this case, the Dalvik JVM) that the interrupt has arrived

The size of the Linux kernel is huge (more than 9 millions of lines of code). To understand which file is executed you need to know at least the type of I/O event and the type of I/O controller.

Answer (score 1):

The linux kernel doesn't handle activities, some process running inside Dalvik (the not-so-java VM) does.

Answer (score 1):

The basic fact is Android activity has nothing to do with your kernel directly. So it is not a valid question to ask at first. Actually when you get your activity displayed on screen, plenty of things happens, enabling the touch sensor, adjusting the backlight of your screen and ofcourse setting up the frame buffer for display, to name a few. Each of these internally invokes several kernel drivers handling different devices. I hope this helps you understand the answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you touch the screen to do some activity. The touch screen manager will call kernel to determine the touch screen coordinates to pass the info to appropriate application. The kernel will use touch screen driver which is part of the kernel to calculate the touch screen location and it will be passed to the user space program. The exact mechanism may be device file interface or some system call interface.